# in python pandas data frame shift values from Category to Rating, Rating to Reviews, ............ ,Current Ver to Android Ver

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

This is my main data:
[image: This is my main data]

I need to change this line of data:
[image: I need to change this line of data]

This is my output:
[image: I got output like this]

In python pandas data frame shift values from Category to Rating, Rating to Reviews, etc. Current Ver to Android Ver. App column should be constant.
I tried a lot. But its not giving me the proper output. Please help me

Comment: please no images, provide data as text, code as text…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df["Price"]=="Everyone", "Category":"Android Ver"] = df.loc[df["Price"]=="Everyone", "Category":"Android Ver"].shift(axis=1)
```